# Is it possible that getters and setters be made abstract in an abstract?

Tags: java

```
public abstract class Modeller {
    private String model;
     abstract void getModel();
    abstract void setModel(String model);
```

Is it possible having something like this. If so how well is it implemented because what code snippet I have above runs with errors.

Comment: An abstract class can have abstract methods but those can't have a body (otherwise they wouldn't be abstract anymore). What are you trying to achieve with this construct? I don't see any need for that getter and setter to be abstract.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

Your code violates the rule that abstract methods have no body.

## Details

An abstract class in Java can have:

- Methods that are concrete (implemented).
- Methods that are abstract (not implemented).

Another class extending that abstract class:

- *May* override the concrete methods
- *Must* implement the abstract methods.

Your **example code is *not* proper Java code** because you have `abstract` methods that carry an implementation. By definition, an abstract method has no implementation.

Side issue: Your getter method must return something, but you declared it `void`.

Side issue: A private member field is not visible to subclass. So change that scope if you want abstract methods.

(By the way, single `l` in "modeler")

Modify your code to either be this:

```java
public abstract class Modeler {
    // Fields
    String model;

    // Methods
    abstract String getModel() ;
    abstract void setModel( String model ) ;
}
```

(See a working [example of this at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/Nperfi))

… or this:

```
public abstract class Modeler {
    // Fields
    private String model;

    // Methods
    String getModel(){
        return this.model;
    }
    void setModel( String model ){
        this.model = model;
    }
}
```

See a working [example of this code at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/wlcRIw).

---

I have ignored the issue of whether or not this is smart handling of getter/setter accessor methods. I want to focus on your specific question of how to do abstract methods.

Comment: @BasilBourque I have made changes to my post so can you now please answer the question..